# jqgrid generate unique rowid when add inline rows

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

15.1
pleas this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dnfk8hmr/54/)

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/dnfk8hmr/53/
```

i want when add new record to grid generate unique rowID 
when remove rowID jgrid generate unique rowID  with jqg2 ,jqg3 
iam dont need  this .i want  Custom generate unique rowID

```
.jqGrid('inlineNav',
                {
                    edit: true, add: true, save: true, cancel: true,
                    addParams: {
                        position: "last", //ردیف‌های جدید در آخر ظاهر می
                      //  rowID: '_empty',
                        useDefValues: true,

                    },

                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can define `rowID` as **callback function**. For example, you can use

```js
addParams: {
    position: "last",
    rowID: function (options) {
        return 123 + $.jgrid.guid++;
    },
    useDefValues: true
}
```

where `123` is the start value and `$.jgrid.guid` is just a counter provided by jqGrid. You can use of cause any other way to generate ids.

The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dnfk8hmr/60/ demonstrates which meaning could have `options` parameter. It contains just all options of `addRow` method used in the current call. I used in the demo the code

```js
addParams: {
    position: "last",
    startId: 123, 
    rowID: function (options) {
        return options.startId + $.jgrid.guid++;
    },
    useDefValues: true
}
```

only to demonstrate, that one can use *custom* options almost anywhere in jqGrid.